# How to have single connection for each device in MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: android, mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas, stitch

I have an Android that uses firebase for authentication and MongoDb as a backend, I'm currently on the M0 cluster where the connection limit is 500. I use the Stitch API. When I use app from my device the number of connections increases from 4 to 8. I think initial 4 connections are by default so I don't mind that but I'm really concerned about such a jump in number of connections from a single device.
PS. I tried having StitchAppClient and RemoteMongoClient in common class, so that there would be a single instance, but that too didn't work.

I'm attaching the connection graph below, please help.[image]

Comment: What connections are being counted? An application connected to a 3 node replica set deployment uses a minimum of 4 connections, 1 monitoring connection per node + at least 1 connection for queries/writes.

Comment: So that means I would have 4 connections per user (of my app)?

Comment: Per running application process.