# Number of connections per client on MongoDB Realm

Tags: realm, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471878/how-to-have-single-connection-for-each-device-in-mongodb-atlas#comment112240385_63471878), there's a minimum of 4 connections per "running application process" on MongoDB Realm, three of these four are constant (monitoring connections) and the rest depends on the number of queries/writes. As I understand, each Realm synchronized is another connection.

A complex app can have multiple Realms synchronized, meaning it wouldn't be hard to have 10 open connections. Does this mean that even paying for the highest cluster tier (M700, $33.26/hr) the app couldn't have more than 12800 (128000 connections / 10 open connections per client) active users?